# Plain Html and javascript execution offline

Tags: html, offline-browsing

Can HTML and javascript run offline like an application? I'm looking to running the webpage offline like silverlight OOB applications. But if the browser closes, I want some way to run the webpage again without going online. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML 5 draft introduces [mechanisms for a webpage to be used as an offline application](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html) although, obviously, as a recent draft spec this isn't supported by all browsers.

You can also *File > Save As* and just save an HTML file and its associated JS locally.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) provides the kind of functionality that you're looking for. Google themselves are planning on phasing it out in favour of HTML5's draft (see David's response) but I think you will find Gears more mature [for the time being, at least], and (perhaps importantly, if you're considering redistribution) more consistent across different browsers.

[Further edit:] The [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/develop/ajax/) runtime allows you to run HTML and JavaScript applications on the desktop.

Comment: does the client have to install gears?

Comment: Yes. Gears is a browser plugin, not a magic piece of JavaScript that gives all sorts of access to the user's system.